# sqlalchemy: union query few columns from multiple tables with condition

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to adapt some part of a MySQLdb application to sqlalchemy in declarative base. I'm only beginning with sqlalchemy.

The legacy tables are defined something like:

```
student: id_number*, semester*, stateid, condition, ...
choice: id_number*, semester*, choice_id, school, program, ...
```

We have 3 tables for each of them (`student_tmp`, `student_year`, `student_summer`, `choice_tmp`, `choice_year`, `choice_summer`), so each pair (`_tmp`, `_year`, `_summer`) contains information for a specific moment.

```
select *
from `student_tmp`
    inner join `choice_tmp` using (`id_number`, `semester`)
```

My problem is the information that is important to me is to get the equivalent of the following select:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
        (
            SELECT st.*, ct.*
            FROM `student_tmp` AS st
                INNER JOIN `choice_tmp` as ct USING (`id_number`, `semester`)
            WHERE (ct.`choice_id` = IF(right(ct.`semester`, 1)='1', '3', '4'))
                AND (st.`condition` = 'A')
        ) UNION (
            SELECT sy.*, cy.*
            FROM `student_year` AS sy
                INNER JOIN `choice_year` as cy USING (`id_number`, `semester`)
            WHERE (cy.`choice_id` = 4)
                AND (sy.`condition` = 'A')
        ) UNION (
            SELECT ss.*, cs.*
            FROM `student_summer` AS ss
                INNER JOIN `choice_summer` as cs USING (`id_number`, `semester`)
            WHERE (cs.`choice_id` = 3)
                AND (ss.`condition` = 'A')
        )
    ) as t
```

`*` used for shorten the select, but I'm actually only querying for about 7 columns out of the 50 availables.

This information is used in many flavors... "Do I have new students? Do I still have all students from a given date? Which students are subscribed after the given date? etc..." The result of this select statement is to be saved in another database.

Would it be possible for me to achieve this with a single view-like class? The information is read-only so I don't need to be able to modify/create/delte. Or do I have to declare a class for each table (ending up with 6 classes) and every time I need to query, I have to remember to filter?

Thanks for pointers.

*EDIT*: I don't have modification access to the database (I cannot create a view). Both databases may not be on the same server (so I cannot create a view on my second DB).

My concern is to avoid the full table scan before filtering on `condition` and `choice_id`.

*EDIT 2*: I've set up declarative classes like this:

```
class BaseStudent(object):
    id_number = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(7), primary_key=True)
    semester = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(5), primary_key=True)
    unique_id_number = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(7))
    stateid = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(12))
    condition = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(3))

class Student(BaseStudent, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'student'

    choices = orm.relationship('Choice', backref='student')

#class StudentYear(BaseStudent, Base):...
#class StudentSummer(BaseStudent, Base):...

class BaseChoice(object):
    id_number = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(7), primary_key=True)
    semester = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(5), primary_key=True)
    choice_id = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(1))
    school = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(2))
    program = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.String(5))


class Choice(BaseChoice, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'choice'

    __table_args__ = (
            sqlalchemy.ForeignKeyConstraint(['id_number', 'semester',],
                [Student.id_number, Student.semester,]),
            )

#class ChoiceYear(BaseChoice, Base): ...
#class ChoiceSummer(BaseChoice, Base): ...
```

Now, the query that gives me correct SQL for one set of table is:

```
q = session.query(StudentYear, ChoiceYear) \
            .select_from(StudentYear) \
            .join(ChoiceYear) \
            .filter(StudentYear.condition=='A') \
            .filter(ChoiceYear.choice_id=='4')
```

but it throws an exception...

```
"Could not locate column in row for column '%s'" % key)
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchColumnError: "Could not locate column in row for column '*'"
```

How do I use that query to create myself a class I can use?

Comment: What is `Social` model referenced in FK of `Choice`?

Comment: Sorry, it's supposed to be Student, updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can create this view on the database, then you simply map the view as if it was a table. See [Reflecting Views](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/schema.html#reflecting-views).

```
# DB VIEW
CREATE VIEW my_view AS -- @todo: your select statements here

# SA
my_view = Table('my_view', metadata, autoload=True)
# define view object
class ViewObject(object):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "ViewObject %s" % str((self.id_number, self.semester,))
# map the view to the object
view_mapper = mapper(ViewObject, my_view)

# query the view
q = session.query(ViewObject)
for _ in q:
    print _
```

If you cannot create a `VIEW` on the database level, you could create a selectable and map the `ViewObject` to it. The code below should give you the idea:

```
student_tmp = Table('student_tmp', metadata, autoload=True)
choice_tmp = Table('choice_tmp', metadata, autoload=True)
# your SELECT part with the columns you need
qry = select([student_tmp.c.id_number, student_tmp.c.semester, student_tmp.stateid, choice_tmp.school])
# your INNER JOIN condition
qry = qry.where(student_tmp.c.id_number == choice_tmp.c.id_number).where(student_tmp.c.semester == choice_tmp.c.semester)
# other WHERE clauses
qry = qry.where(student_tmp.c.condition == 'A')
```

You can create 3 queries like this, then combine them with [union_all](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/expression_api.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.union_all) and use the resulting query in the mapper:

```
view_mapper = mapper(ViewObject, my_combined_qry)
```

In both cases you have to ensure though that a PrimaryKey is properly defined on the view, and you might need to `override` the autoloaded view, and specify the primary key explicitely (see the link above). Otherwise you will either receive an error, or might not get proper results from the query.

---

**Answer to EDIT-2:**

```
qry = (session.query(StudentYear, ChoiceYear).
        select_from(StudentYear).
        join(ChoiceYear).
        filter(StudentYear.condition == 'A').
        filter(ChoiceYear.choice_id == '4')
        )
```

The result will be tuple pairs: `(Student, Choice)`.
But if you want to create a new mapped class for the query, then you can create a selectable as the sample above:

```
student_tmp = StudentTmp.__table__
choice_tmp = ChoiceTmp.__table__
.... (see sample code above)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have modification access to the DB, only data read-only access to that database. I though of creating the view on my database, but this may not work if databases are on different serveurs.

Comment: @Danosaure: edited the answer with the possibility to map it when cannot create DB objects.

Comment: Can this be done declarative base? I have setup my classes. I have problem to define `condition=='A'` in my `primaryjoin` of the `orm.relationship`.

Comment: Sure it can. To get `student_tmp` table from the class `StudentTmp` you just do `StudentTmp.__table__`.

Comment: You cannot use the `'*'` here. Replace those with query for tuple. Will update the answer by adding this...

Comment: Right... I didn't see clearly when pasting and editing. Given that,  can I use the query as a class, or something equivalent?

Comment: You cannot use a query as a class, but you can map a query (selectable) to a class as I showed in the code already in the answer. I extended a bit the answer to **edit-2** to show you how to get to tables from your classes as the basis for selectable.

Comment: I'm a little slow, but I will eventually understand :)  I though the `mapper()` with the `select()` was classical base and not declarative base, so I was trying to look into `Query()`, but your `select` from your answer gave me a good hint to get it done. See my answer for what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

This is to show what I ended up doing, any comment welcomed.

```
class JoinedYear(Base):
    __table__ = sqlalchemy.select(
            [
                StudentYear.id_number,
                StudentYear.semester,
                StudentYear.stateid,
                ChoiceYear.school,
                ChoiceYear.program,
                ],
                from_obj=StudentYear.__table__.join(ChoiceYear.__table__),
                ) \
                .where(StudentYear.condition == 'A') \
                .where(ChoiceYear.choice_id == '4') \
                .alias('YearView')
```

and I will elaborate from there...

Thanks @van